# CSV Connection into Named Table not Range

Tags: excel

If you make a data connection to another Excel file or an Access table it will import that data into excel as a Table.  This is great!  But when I do the same with "From Text" and choose a CSV, it loads no problem, but it loads as a RANGE not a TABLE.  This is highly frustrating as I *NEED* it to be in the table format so that I can take advantage of the dynamic column names.

Am I missing a tickbox somewhere?  I'm not opposed to using VBA but it really seems odd that Excel can't do CSV to Table so I'm hoping for a native solution.

I should mention that if it's a VBA solution, it CANT break the workbook.  So if I'm doing something like:

```
=SUMIFS(CSVDATA[SalesDollars], CSVDATA[RepName], "BOB")
```

It will still work after refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can get around the 'data connection' not creating a table by downloading the MS Excel 2010 plugin (from Microsoft) called Power Query. It's free and is a default feature in MS Excel 2013.

It will allow you to choose to *create a Power Query Table from External Data* *>> From File >> From CSV*

Upon doing this, it will create a named table for you and a Power Query object attached to the table. You can use the table itself the same way you normally would - with the Columns as references for formulas.

For instance, the default table that I just created using the steps above was auto-named: **Table_ExternalData_1**

I can then select it using the normal method in formulas:

```
=Table_ExternalData_1[Column2]
```

etc...

Hope that helps.

Comment: If someone else gets my sheet that doesn't have Power Query, would they be able to press refresh all and have the CSV update?

Comment: I believe refresh is enabled only to people with Power Query, that is the only limiter at present for 2010 users. Anyone on 2013 will, by default, be able to refresh the data connection data. I believe the intent in 2013 was to replace the existing data connections model and enhance it with the new functionality.

Comment: This is probably the only way to do this eh?  I don't think a VBA hack would work since creating/recreating the table through a script would likely be volatile... I may have to find a way to extract my data into either excel or ms access first then have excel pull it in the way I like it.  I'm inclined to give you the right answer anyway since it seems to be a software issue and this is Microsoft's "fix" for it (even though I don't like it!)

Comment: Another thought is you could potentially convert your CSV files to XLSX files ahead of using them, then use the data connection (standard) to an Excel file... Look at running a batch to convert them. The challenge being if in the batch cut-over, MS Excel may convert some of the data for you... Like dates, as it is apt to do.

Comment: I'm actually using R to do the data dump.. so I can easily just have it export the XLS.. but first I need IT to install Java on my Virtual Desktop.. also it's very limited on ram and I fear it may crash on bigger datasets